# Advice How to make this query perform well

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a schema in postgress 9.2.0 that resembles this

```
CREATE TABLE emails
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  subject text,
  body text,
  CONSTRAINT emails_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE email_participants
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  kind text NOT NULL,
  email_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT email_participants_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT email_participants_email_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (email_id)
  REFERENCES emails (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE todos
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description text,
  reference_email_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT todos_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT todos_reference_email_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (reference_email_id)
  REFERENCES emails (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX todos_reference_email_id_index
  ON todos
  USING btree
  (reference_email_id);

CREATE TABLE calls
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description text,
  reference_email_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT calls_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT calls_reference_email_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (reference_email_id)
  REFERENCES emails (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX calls_reference_email_id_index
  ON calls
  USING btree
  (reference_email_id);

CREATE TABLE meetings
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description text,
  reference_email_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT meetings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT meetings_reference_email_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (reference_email_id)
  REFERENCES emails (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX meetings_reference_email_id_index
  ON meetings
  USING btree
  (reference_email_id);

CREATE TABLE attachments
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description text,
  reference_email_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT attachments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT attachments_reference_email_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (reference_email_id)
  REFERENCES emails (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX attachments_reference_email_id_index
  ON attachments
  USING btree
  (reference_email_id);
```

All the email_id columns above have foreign key constraints on them.

There are other tables that reference the emails table but you get the general idea.

I need to select all the emails and a count or the ids of any of the referenced rows in the email_participants, todos, calls, meetings, attachments

So the most obvious thing that springs to mind is to inner join on email_participants and left outer join on the other tables:

```
SELECT * FROM "emails" e INNER JOIN "email_participants" ep
ON ep.email_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN TODOS t
on e.id = t.reference_email_id
LEFT JOIN Calls c
on e.id = c.reference_email_id
LEFT JOIN meetings m
on e.id = m.reference_email_id
LEFT JOIN Attachments at
on e.id = at.reference_email_id
WHERE ("user_id" = 1)
```

If I use explain I get the following query plan which I am afraid I don't really understand:

```
"Hash Right Join  (cost=51.11..68.16 rows=123 width=1047)"
"  Hash Cond: (t.reference_email_id = e.id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on todos t  (cost=0.00..14.30 rows=430 width=157)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=50.44..50.44 rows=53 width=890)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.06..50.44 rows=53 width=890)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.06..41.78 rows=15 width=797)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=23.06..37.78 rows=7 width=645)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=23.06..35.58 rows=4 width=458)"
"                                Hash Cond: (e.id = ep.email_id)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on emails e  (cost=0.00..11.80 rows=180 width=410)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=23.00..23.00 rows=5 width=48)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on email_participants ep  (cost=0.00..23.00 rows=5 width=48)"
"                                            Filter: (user_id = 1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using meetings_reference_email_id_index on meetings m  (cost=0.00..0.53 rows=2 width=187)"
"                                Index Cond: (e.id = reference_email_id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using attachments_reference_email_id_index on attachments at  (cost=0.00..0.55 rows=2 width=152)"
"                          Index Cond: (e.id = reference_email_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using calls_reference_email_id_index on calls c  (cost=0.00..0.55 rows=3 width=93)"
"                    Index Cond: (e.id = reference_email_id)"
```

This sql needs to be the most performant I can possibly make it, is there anything else I can do to make this faster or avoid all these left joins?  There are lots of these join tables.

Would creating a view make this better and if so, can anyone give any advice on creating such a view?

Comment: What indexes are in place?

Comment: Did you examine the query plan?

Comment: Put Explain in front of it, see what it says.

Comment: First, add some PK's anf FK's to the table definitions, like in `id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` and  `email_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES emails(id)`

Comment: A union query might perform better.

Comment: I have added the primary, foreign key and indexes that I am currently using

Comment: I have added the explain query plan also

Answer (score 1):

If you join a parent record to multiple child records in different tables, you get the problem of 10 child records in table A and 20 child records in table B producing 200 records in the final result.

You'll probably do better with counts like this:

```
create view ...
select ...,
       (select count(*) from  child_table_1
                        where foreign_key = parent_key) child_1_count,
       (select count(*) from  child_table_2
                        where foreign_key = parent_key) child_2_count,
       ...
from   parent_table
where  user_id = 1
```

Edit: this also has the advantage that when running a query that omits child count columns against this view, the optimiser avoids including that code path.

Another edit: To return id's, they really need to be returned as separate queries, but you could try an array aggregation with string conversion to return a list of id's to the app -- otherwise you'd be best off with a UNION ALL between multiple queries (one per child table), or in fact one query per child table.

```
(select array_to_string(array_agg(reference_email_id), ',')
   from child_table_2
  where foreign_key = parent_key) child_2_id_list,
```

Comment: I like this idea, what about if I needed the ids and not the counts?